# Baking two objects to one texture

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

As the picture shows I have leaves, where every leaf is a separate plane, and a ground. They are unwrapped (see below), and I don't know how to bake these leaves onto the ground so that only the ground has geometry, and I can delete the old leaf planes. Do you know how to make this?

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking. Could you try to explain a little deeper?

Comment: I have one object with contains leaves and ground. Leaves have geometry, they are planes and I want to get rid of this geometry so I want to bake them (leaves) in to ground material.

Comment: Are they particles?

Comment: forgot to mation ground and leaves have separate material

Comment: They were particles but I converted them in to object

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I assume that one leaf was made, used as a particle system which was applied as an object and then this leaves object was already joined to ground object to create one object but the vertices of the leaves have the leaf texture and the ground vertices have the ground texture. Is that correct?

It looks like you already have each thing unwrapped into one UV map so if I've understood you correctly baking two assigned materials into one diffuse material is what you want to do, correct?

Baking two material textures into one:

1) Open the node editor and the UV image editor. In the UV image editor create a new image and give it the dimensions you want your new diffuse image texture to be. Make sure the dimensions are quite big because it gives you the option to scale it down if you want to crop it. Now save it to a location you can remember.

2) Go to node editor, click on your object and go into material of either object and add an image texture. DO NOT CONNECT IT TO ANYTHING. Now open your new blank image inside the image texture you added (the image which you created and saved earlier).

3) In the render tab, scroll down until you see "Bake". Expand the tab and choose Diffuse (it should be the default option). With the image texture selected in the node editor (make sure it's highlighted) click "Bake". This should create a new material which includes the leaf materials for each leaf plane in your object.

4) Now you should be able to delete the leaf planes and use the new texture on your ground plane. If you want to, use GIMP or photoshop to crop the newly baked image so that there are no transparent parts. Now you can UV unwrap the ground plane again so it fills the UV map and align it to the newly cropped baked image texture so it all lines up if it doesn't already.

You can also create a normal map using the same method by duplicating the ground plane, deleting the leaf geometry in edit mode and UV unwrap it. In the bake tab, choose "Normal", select your complete mesh and shift select your new edited ground plane mesh second and in the bake tab click the option "Selected to Active". Then click "Bake".

Remember to duplicate everything and move it to a different layer or save a back up file before you do anything so that you don't lose everything if you make a mistake.

If I've missed a step, please feel free to edit my answer because I'm away from my PC and can't double check :)

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got it, you want to have no more leaves, but to have their geometry directly projected on the ground plane.

In this case you need to:

- go to Object mode;
- select all the leaves;
- if they are separate objects press <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> to join them in a single object;
- when you have all the leaves in one object and selected them, add the ground plane to the selection right clicking on it (while pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>);
- switch to edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd> (you should now be editing the ground plane in edit mode, with the leaves selected but not active);
- find the button "Knife project" on the left bar (or simply press <kbd>SPACEBAR</kbd> and start writing "Knife project" until the command appears in the menu) and click it;

Now you should have the leaves projected on the ground and you can go back to Object mode and delete them.
The problem is that you don't keep the leaves Material. Their geometry is just projected on to the ground plane.

If you want the texture to be projected on the ground, you should render the scene from a orthographic camera that looks vertically down on the plane from above and use this as a new texture for the ground.

Comment: not exactly I want leaves to just be in textures normal maps and rest but not as a part of geometry, like for exaple we sculpt something but we don't want to have so much faces so we bake them as a material and retopologys them.

Comment: Ok! Than you should try the last part of my tip, rendering the texture from the top. With post processing you can separately get textures for color, zdepth, and other things.